# How do I convert a Coqui Tensorflow model to .tflite?

Tags: tensorflow, speech-to-text, tensorflow-lite, coqui

I have the Coqui STT [yesno model](https://github.com/coqui-ai/STT-models/releases/tag/english%2Fcoqui%2Fyesno-v0.0.1) from GitHub, which is an ultra-compact speech recognition model that only recognises two words: yes and no.

I have the `yesno.pbmm` and `yesno.scorer` files.

I also have a tarball `coqui-yesno-checkpoints.tar.gz` containing the following files:

```
ls -l coqui-yesno-checkpoints/
total 7356
-rw-r--r-- 1 jeremiah jeremiah      12 Jul 27 00:00 alphabet.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 jeremiah jeremiah 1066076 Jul 26 23:59 best_dev-1909.data-00000-of-00001
-rw-r--r-- 1 jeremiah jeremiah    1377 Jul 26 23:59 best_dev-1909.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 jeremiah jeremiah 4476795 Jul 26 23:59 best_dev-1909.meta
-rw-r--r-- 1 jeremiah jeremiah      83 Jul 27 00:00 best_dev_checkpoint
-rw-r--r-- 1 jeremiah jeremiah    3861 Jul 27 00:02 flags.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 jeremiah jeremiah 1368905 Jul 27 00:05 yesno-64dims.logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 jeremiah jeremiah  594622 Jul 27 00:05 yesno-64dims.logs.lm-optimizer
```

How do I convert this model into a `.tflite` file for use with Coqui on embedded devices?

Looking for a command-line solution that can be easily scripted.

Comment: FYI, here is the document you may be interested in:  https://stt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Coqui STT is forked from Mozilla's DeepSpeech. I wrote the [PlayBook](https://mozilla.github.io/deepspeech-playbook/DEPLOYMENT.html) for DeepSpeech, alongside Josh Meyer, one of the founders of Coqui. The [Coqui STT training documentation](https://stt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/TRAINING_INTRO.html#) doesn't cover *exporting* a model to `tflite`, so I would recommend starting from the DeepSpeech documentation - as the syntax is generally interchangeable.

That is, you need to run `train.py` from Coqui, specifying the checkpoints you have, and pass the `--export_tflite` flag. This should create a `tflite` model from the checkpoints. By default, DeepSpeech would export a `protobuf` (`.pb`) file, but I don't know what Coqui's default export format is.

At a *guess*, this would look something like:

```
python3 train.py \
  --train_files [location of your train csv] \
  --dev_files [location of your dev csv] \
  --test_files [location of your test csv] \
  --checkpoint_dir [location of your checkpoints] \
  --export_dir [where you want your model exported to] \
  --export_tflite
```

Hope this helps - interested to hear how you go.